# Is it considered good practice to use Task.ContinueWith() as a form of event "TaskEnded"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

`Task` doesn't have a completed event/method that I can use to execute follow up code. If `Task` were to execute a long running operation (such as downloading data from the web to update a local database), is it considered good practice to use the method `Task.ContinueWith()` for executing an on completed like event? Are there any unwanted side effects or issues I may run into with this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fine to use `ContinueWith()` to follow up on completion of long-running operations. However, as of .NET 4.5 there is a more concise way to write this, which is to use the `async`/`await` keywords. For instance:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(...))
{
    // long-running download operation, but UI remains responsive because
    // the operation executes asynchronously

    var response = await client.GetAsync();

    // control resumes here once the above completes,
    // returning control to the UI thread.

    this.TextField.Text = "Download Complete!";
}
```

You can interpret whatever happens after the `await` as the *continuation*, i.e. the stuff you would normally put in your `ContinueWith()`. The `await` has the effect of waiting for the operation to complete, unwrapping the result from the returned task, and resuming execution on the current context - in this case the UI thread.

This is a great way to carry out long-running I/O operations and still have a responsive UI. You will need to do this in an `async` method - see the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Oh I thought `await` blocked the execution. So it returns to the caller as if the method was finished, and then when the `async` method being awaited upon finally returns, then execution resumes at the statement right bellow the asynchronous call, is that it?

Comment: `await` just allows the UI to continue processing while waiting for the method to finish executing. This is what you are looking for @KauanRmk

Comment: Yes, exactly. The point of await is to allow long-running operations to occur without blocking the current context (in this case the UI thread). This is particularly important on platforms such as Windows Phone where there is a hard limit on the amount of time the UI can block (some 50ms if I'm not mistaken).